# Unable to deploy helm chart on remote kubernetes server using org.unbroken-dome.helm plugin

Tags: build.gradle, kubernetes-helm, gradle-plugin

I prefer https://unbroken-dome.github.io/projects/gradle-helm-plugin/ gradle plugin to deploy one of my application using helm chart on remote kubernetes cluster.

Please find below code snippet :

plugin and import section :

```
plugins {
   id 'org.unbroken-dome.helm' version '1.0.0'
   id 'org.unbroken-dome.helm-commands' version '1.0.0'
}
import org.unbrokendome.gradle.plugins.helm.command.tasks.*
```

gradle task section :

```
  helm {
        kubeConfig = file('src/main/resources/helm/kubeconfig')
        charts {
            app_chart {
                chartVersion = "1.0.0"
                filtering {
                    values.put 'imageRepository', "test-repo/appImage"
                    values.put 'imageTag', "1.0.0"
                }
                sourceDir = file 'src/main/resources/helm/app-helm'
            } 
        }
    }

task installApp(type: HelmInstallOrUpgrade) {
    releaseName = 'app-release'
    from helm.charts.app_chart
}
```

Execute task by command : `gradle installApp`

But getting error like `commandLine[index - 1] must not be null`. Please help to solve this error. Thanks in advance to reply.